# Characterizing $\frac{m^k - e^{-x}(m+1)^k}{k!}$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, gamma-function, digamma-function

I'm trying to characterize the behavior this function: $l_k(m,x)=\frac{m^k - e^{-x}(m+1)^k}{k!}$.

I was wondering whether either of these functions are well-known in the probability theory and statistics literature:

$l_k(m,x)$

or

$\sum_{k=0}^m x^k l_k(m,x)$.

I appreciate if some similar papers in which these types of functions are used can be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, since $m$ is a constant, that the second question is $$S_m=\sum_{k=0}^m x^\color{red}{k} \,l_k(m,x)$$ I am curious to know in which particular context you had to work it; in my research group, we had the same problem in thermodynamics and the solution is
$$S_m=e^{mx} \,\frac{\Gamma (m+1,m x)-\Gamma (m+1,(m+1) x)}{\Gamma (m+1)}$$

Similarly
$$T_m=\sum_{k=0}^m  \,l_k(m,x)=e^m \,\frac{\Gamma (m+1,m)-e^{1-x} \Gamma (m+1,m+1)}{\Gamma (m+1)}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
Yes, the superscript of $x$ in series is $k$ not $m$, I edited my post.
The context of my research is related to probability theory and queueing systems, and I used the difference of incomplete gamma function to obtain the $l_k$ to sort of simplify the equation. The function which I'm working with right now is quite similar to your $S_m$, but having lower incomplete gamma function instead of the upper one.